# Display name against column value in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table called Calls that contains some call logs and want to run a report that tells me how many times a phone number was used and location name instead of a serial number. The table is like this:

```
record#   phone     serial 
1         1001      111111 
2         1001      111111 
3         1002      222222 
4         1003      111111
```

I've got this so far:

```
select phone, count(phone) From Calls group by phone
```

which gives me:

```
1001   2
1002   1
1003   1
```

But I also want to include the serial but display it as a name so 111111 would be 'London'

i.e

```
1001   2  London
1002   1  Glasgow
1003   1  London
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: where do you have the serial name? is that stored in a table?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT `phone`, count(`phone`), 
    CASE
        WHEN `serial` = '11111' THEN 'London' 
        WHEN `serial` = '22222' THEN 'Glasgo'
        ELSE `serial`
    END AS `city`
FROM `Calls` group by `phone`
```

Comment: that is throwing an error saying "serial is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either the aggregate function or the group by clause"

Comment: excellent got it now just added the serial to the group by. You may have gathered I know very little about SQL but thanks for all your help and patience :)